# vanity url with .htaccess in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to create a vanity url for where users profile could easily be viewed by others.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/test/public/profile.php?username=$1 [NC]
```

This is the code but each time i use this code in my .htaccess file, i get 500 Internal Server Error and the sub-folder *public* disappears from my directory. What am i getting wrong? Do i need any to do any configuration first?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use global rewrite logic:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

and in Your index.php catch **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']** and if user exists so respond if not then pass processing to next procedure.

But if You insist on realization as in question so try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I just tried that out but still same. This is what shows up on my browser "Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error. More information about this error may be available in the server error log."

Comment: seems like rewrite engine is not turned on. try: sudo a2enmod rewrite     and then restart apache

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. The rewrite engine was actually turned off. i found another way of turning it on.                                                         To enable the mod_rewrite using the wampmanager menu system:

left click the wampmanager icon ( thats the W icon that sits in the system tray, usually bottom right of your screen )

wampmanager -> Apache -> Apache modules -> and click the line [rewrite_module] if it is not ticked
You may have to scroll the menu down to find rewrite_module

Comment: wamp... (: use normal web server or use "php -S" directive..   happy that fixed issue

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^profile/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-/]+)$ test/public/profile.php?username=$1 [L,NC]
    </IfModule>
```

However note:

1. You must have the rewrite engine on to make it work (google a bit for the installation procedure the OS/system you are working)
2. Put proper `RewriteBase` directive if you use it from subdirectory.

Comment: I just tried that out but still same. This is what shows up on my browser                                                                                           "Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log."